# Problem connecting to my Samba server on ubuntu from my windows computer

Tags: networking, server, samba

I'm doing a school project where i have to set up a basic samba server on linux to share files between 2 computers (i only need to show it working), one computer is a laptop running linux on a virtual console where i set up the server, and the other one is my windows desktop computer where i try to access the files on the samba server, but i cant get it to work! i have the server running but i just cant connect my desktop computer to it. My smb.conf file looks like this.

```
[global]
; General server settings
netbios name = YOUR_HOSTNAME
server string =
workgroup = YOUR_WORKGROUP
announce version = 5.0
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 
SO_SNDBUF=8192

passdb backend = tdbsam
security = user
null passwords = true
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
name resolve order = hosts wins bcast
wins support = yes


printing = CUPS
printcap name = CUPS

syslog = 1
syslog only = yes

[print$]
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
write list = root
create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0775

[printers]
path = /tmp
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
browseable = no

[MyFiles]
path = /home/samba/
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = YOUR_USERNAME
force group = YOUR_USERGROUP
```

I have also tried changing security to = share so it doesnt ask for a user or password and anyone connected to the network can access the server but i still cant find the server on my windows computer

Answer (score 1):

When i have problems with samba I'm always starting from switching to ethernet cable. If my share is connected via ethernet i cant connect to it via wifi (eventhough I can ssh with no problem). Then i make easiest share possible with no fancy masks end forcing options, only to test if it works. If not then I'm checking logs to see if it's stopped by any security mechanism (it could be firewall, iptables, selinux). For home usage I'm switching all security off and test it again. Then, if it works I form my share policy in smb.conf and reset smb and nmb. And them I'm checking if my share still works. And then I switch my security back on, one by one to find which one is blocking my smb. This is how you can learn using selinux. I forgot to mention most improtant thing. Alwayas check premissions, and host part of samba configuration. You must be shure that you have unix premissions on your share.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure you have a user configured for Samba. Try smbpasswd -a [user] (needs to map to a unix user). Also try setting your log level higher and look in /var/log/samba/log.smbd for clues, it should also create a log.[clientname] as well, once a user can connect anyway. If you are still having an issue, try to connect to the share and post some logs from the exchange.

Comment: but if i set security = share, shouldn't anyone one the net be able to access the server? also, do you think the fact that the laptop running the server is connected trough wifi instead of ethernet cable is causing the problem? i can connect to the server on my laptop on windows, works awesome but when i try on my desktop pc i cant connect, so i think is not a problem with the server itself but a connectivity problem, that why i ask if wifi might be the problem

Comment: I think security = share is deprecated, at least on most recent versions of Linux, you should have Samba 4. My Ubuntu 14.04 box has 4.1.6. You should probably be using 'security = user' and 'map to guest = bad user' in the global section, and change 'guest ok = yes'  for your MyFiles share if you want anyone to connect. Although, if it is working from one system and not another, it could be a connectivity issue.  Can you ping the server from the desktop? Do you have any other connectivity between those systems?